# PHP GET method doesn't work in Xampps

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in PHP and I'm confused about GET method.

Why the `$text` in the condition of the loop works with Appserv in Windows 7, but when I tried this code with Xampps on Mac it won't work I've to use `for($i=0; $i<strlen($_GET['text']); $i++)` instead.

At first, I understand that after I used `isset($_GET['text'])` so next time I just use only `$text`, but now I'm confused.

```
<? $color = array("#FFCCFF", "#FFCCCC", "#FFCC99", "#FF99FF", "#FF99CC",
    "#FF9999", "#FF66FF", "#FF66CC", "#FF6699", "#FF6666");
if (isset($_GET['text'])) { 
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++) { 
        $j = $i%10 ?>
        <font color=<?= $color[$j]?>><? echo "$text[$i]"; ?></font>
    } 
} else {
    echo "Empty String";
} ?>
```

The problem is **solved** by many of your help.

```
<?php $color = array("#FFCCFF", "#FFCCCC", "#FFCC99", "#FF99FF", "#FF99CC",
    "#FF9999", "#FF66FF", "#FF66CC", "#FF6699", "#FF6666"); 
if( isset($_GET['text'])) {
    $text = $_GET['text'];
    for( $i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++) {
        $j = $i%10;
        echo "<font color=$color[$j]>$text[$i]</font>";
    }
} else
    echo "Empty string";
?>
```

btw I'm trying to use HTML + PHP only because I want to practice with HTML before go in deep with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer to your question, if `$text` is working as an alias for `$_GET['text']` is probably that your Windows server is configured with `register_globals` set to `on`, which would mean that anything passed over in your query string would be turned into the appropriate variable.

ie. `?awesome=true` == `$awesome = 'true'`

This is bad. Disable `register_globals` at the offending side, and use `$_GET['text']` to access your data.

Your code would look better a little something like this:

```
<?php
$color = array("#FFCCFF", "#FFCCCC", "#FFCC99", "#FF99FF", "#FF99CC",
                "#FF9999", "#FF66FF", "#FF66CC", "#FF6699", "#FF6666");
if (isset($_GET['text'])) {
    $text = $_GET['text'];
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) { 
        $j = $i % 10; ?>
        <span style="color: <?= $color[$j] ?>"><?= htmlentities($text[$i]); ?></span>
    <?php } 
} else {
    echo "Empty String";
}
?>
```

Note that I have tidied up your code and made it slightly more sane/safe. `htmlentities` is used to stop XSS vulns that could come from this, despite being unlikely due to splitting the string. You were mixing up `<?php echo .. ?>` and `<?= .. ?>` for some reason, despite them being the exact same thing. Also, don't use `<font>`.

You said this:

> At first, I understand that "after I used isset($_GET['text']) so next time I just use only($text), but now I'm confused.

If you know you're mixing them, why are you doing it? If you're checking for `$_GET['text']` being set, then it's only logical that you would use that for access also.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, why are you dropping in and out of PHP every line? It is allowed to have more than one line of PHP at a time, you know!

`$_GET['text']` is a variable. Accessing it does nothing special, but it is special in that you can access it regardless of scope (it is superglobal). Referring to is as `$text` only works if the autoregister globals setting is enabled, which is not recommended for various reasons.

So, your code should look like:

```
<?php
$color = array(".....");
if( isset($_GET['text'])) {
    $l = strlen($_GET['text']);
    for( $i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
        $j = $i%10;
        echo "<span style=\"color: ".$color[$j].";\">".$text[$i]."</span>";
    }
}
else echo "Empty string";
?>
```

I also took the liberty of updating your HTML out of the last milennium.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize $text variable first, something like this:

$text = $_GET['text'];

This should work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure as to what you're doing, but:

```
$colours = array("#FFCCFF", "#FFCCCC", "#FFCC99", "#FF99FF", "#FF99CC", "#FF9999", "#FF66FF", "#FF66CC", "#FF6699", "#FF6666");

if (isset($_GET['text'])) {
    $text = $_GET['text'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
        $j = $i%10;
        echo "<span style='color: {$colours[$j]}'>{$text[$i]}</span>";
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No text';
}
```